# Where does the EU ETS fine money go?

Tags: european-union, economy, climate-change

An EU ETS [factsheet](https://ec.europa.eu/clima/sites/clima/files/factsheet_ets_en.pdf) says:

> A business is penalised if it does not surrender enough
>   allowances. It has to buy allowances to make up the shortfall,
>   is “named and shamed” by having its name published, and
>   must pay a fine for each excess tonne of greenhouse gas
>   emitted. In 2013, the fine amounted to €100 per tonne of
>   CO2 (or the equivalent amount of N2O or PFCs). The penalty
>   rises annually in line with the European consumer price
>   index.

Where does this fine money go? Does it go to the member state like the primary auction money, or does it go into some EU budget?

Answer (score 3):

Given that member state authorities devise and impose the fines and the EU ETS [general revenues](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/41593/does-the-eu-ets-primary-auction-money-pass-through-the-eu-coffers-at-all/) themselves remain in the member states I cannot imagine that fines would be used differently. Also the fact that the amount of the fine itself is expressed as a carbon price points in this direction.

Article 16 of [Directive 2003/87/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02003L0087-20180408&from=EN) states that:

> The penalties provided for must be effective, proportionate and
> dissuasive. Member States shall notify these provisions to the
> Commission […]

The 2015 [EU ETS Handbook](https://ec.europa.eu/clima/sites/clima/files/docs/ets_handbook_en.pdf) states:

> This fine is imposed by the relevant Member State authority.